# IntersectionObserver inside useEffect works only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intersection-observer

I am building an infinite scroll app using react and intersection observer api.

But I am stuck at the part that intersectionObserver only once inside useEffect.

Here is the code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createRef } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [passengers, setPassengers] = useState([]);
  const bottomRef = createRef();

  const scrollCallback = (entries) => {
    if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
      axios.get(`https://api.instantwebtools.net/v1/passenger?page=${page}&size=10`).then(res => setPassengers(prevState => [...prevState, ...res.data.data]));
    }
  }; 
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(scrollCallback, {
      root: null,
      threshold: 1,
    });
    observer.observe(bottomRef.current);
    return () => {
      observer.disconnect();
    }
  }, [bottomRef]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="lists">
        {
          passengers.map((passenger, idx) => {
            const { airline, name, trips } = passenger;
              return (
                 <div className="list" key={idx}>
                   <h4>User Info</h4>
                   <p>name: {name}</p>
                   <p>trips: {trips}</p>
                   <h4>Airline Info</h4>
                   <p>name: {airline.name}</p>
                   <p>country: {airline.country}</p>
                   <p>established: {airline.established}</p>
                   <p>head quarter: {airline.head_quarters}</p>
                   <p>website: {airline.website}</p>
                 </div>
              )
            })
        }
      </div>
      <div ref={bottomRef} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

When a scroll hits the bottom, `scrollCallback` function inside useEffect works which merges two arrays into one and eventually shows merged data I want to see.

However this only works once. useEffect lifecycle does not work again. So I changed `observer.disconnect();` to `observer.unobserve(bottomRef.current);` but this occurs an error saying

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'unobserve' on 'IntersectionObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
```

Why `useEffect` lifecycle could not read `bottomRef`??

working code example : https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-newton-jvivj?file=/src/App.js

It is weird that code in codesandbox works

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: `const {current} = bottomRef; observer.observe(current); return () => observer.unobserve(current);`

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi this resolves TypeError but scrollCallback still works once

Comment: @T.J.Crowder got it

Comment: I've edited my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65806370/2800218

Comment: `createRef` should be `useRef`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `useRef`, not `createRef`, and [as Andrea said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65806370/157247), you need to use the same element with `unobserve` that you use with `observe`. Finally, since the thing that your `useEffect` callback uses that varies is `bottomRef.current`, that's the dependency to use in your dependency array.

Here's a working example, see the `***` comments:

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useRef } = React;

function App() {
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
    const [passengers, setPassengers] = useState([]);
    const bottomRef = useRef(null); // *** Not `createRef`

    const scrollCallback = (entries) => {
        if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
            getMorePassengers()
            .then(res => setPassengers(prevState => [...prevState, ...res.data.data]));
            // *** Should handle/report errors here
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        // *** Grab the element related to this callback
        const { current } = bottomRef;
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(scrollCallback, {
            root: null,
            threshold: 1,
        });
        observer.observe(current);
        return () => {
            observer.disconnect(current); // *** Use the same element
        }
    }, [bottomRef.current]); // *** Note dependency

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="lists">
                {
                    passengers.map((passenger, idx) => {
                        // *** I simplified this for the example
                        const { name } = passenger;
                        return (
                            <div className="list" key={idx}>
                                <p>name: {name}</p>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
            <div ref={bottomRef} />
        </div>
    );
}

// ** Stand-in for ajax
let passengerCounter = 0;
function getMorePassengers() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve({
            data: {
                data: [
                    // Obviously, you don't use things like `passengerCounte`
                    {name: `Passenger ${passengerCounter++}`},
                    {name: `Passenger ${passengerCounter++}`},
                    {name: `Passenger ${passengerCounter++}`},
                    {name: `Passenger ${passengerCounter++}`},
                    {name: `Passenger ${passengerCounter++}`},
                ]
            }
        });
    });
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

But you may not need that cleanup callback at all. [Andrea Giammarchi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2800218/andrea-giammarchi) says that `IntersectionObserver` uses weak references to the elements being observed, and A) he's almost always right about things like that, so I believe him; and B) it makes sense that it would be designed that way. So you can probably drop the cleanup callback entirely.

Separately, I'd expect that the `div` you're observing would be created just once, when the component is mounted, and never recreated afterward. So in theory you could just use `[]` as your dependency array.

That said, I'd learn toward retaining the dependency in case React has some reason to recratet that `div`, and I prefer explicit cleanup, so I'd probably leave it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can `observe` a reference, you can surely `unobserve` it too, as long as you have the right, same, reference.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(scrollCallback, {
    root: null,
    threshold: 1,
  });
  const {current} = bottomRef;
  observer.observe(current);
  return () => {
    observer.unobserve(current);
  };
}, [passengers]);
```

This won't ever say `current` is not a node.

**Moreover**, if what changes is `passengers`, you better hold on that reference, instead of holding on something that will never change, because `bottomRef` is the `current` wrapper, but it won't change "*ever*", while the `passengers` state will, once intersected.

**Alternatiely**

As `bottomRef` is not meant to change, you can also just observe that node and never cleanup its observation.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(scrollCallback, {
    root: null,
    threshold: 1,
  });
  observer.observe(bottomRef.current);
}, [bottomRef]);
```

Either ways should solve the issue.

Comment: The dependency should be `[bottomRef.current]` (which will probably never change until the component is unmounted), not `[passengers]`. The div being observed doesn't change when `passengers` changes.

Comment: it cannot be that, because `bottomRef.current` is defined on render, it's `undefined` before (at least the first time)

Comment: Yes, but it won't be by the time the `useEffect` callback is called, because the first call to `useEffect`'s callback is *after* rendering and setting refs. (I'm paranoid so I'd probably have a guard in there anyway, but that's just my paranoia... :-) )

Comment: it doesn't matter ... `useEffect(callback, [THIS_IS_NOW])` cannot pass `bottomRef.current` because that is resolved right away, not after. The point is, if `bottomRef` is always the same, and so is the div, there is no need to return a cleanup function to *unobserve* ...

Comment: I know it's resolved right away, but that's the thing that varies, so that's the thing you use as the dependency. Using `bottomRef` is pointless, it never changes (per guarantee). Returning the callback is important for cleanup on dismount.

Comment: yeah, `[bottomRef]` or `[]` would be the same, the cleanup is not necessary though, as *MutationObserver* uses weak references, nodes that disappear won't leak in there. However, you cannot use `bottomRef.current` as *guard*, because `bottomRef.current` is *undefined* the first time, it exists *inside* useEffect, but not *outside* it, so it's not a guard to suggest because it's *undefined* the first time. Hope this is clear.

Comment: I meant I'd use a guard *inside* the callback (which I know is paranoid). `useEffect(() => { const { current } = bottomRef; if (!current) { return; } /*...*/}, [bottomRef.current]);`. I also prefer explicit cleanup, but if you're sure it's not necessary (which would be good design -- I just haven't used `IntersectionObserver` in a real situation yet), that's great.

Comment: `current`, inside `useEffect`, is *never* undefined. Outside is undefined *the very first time only*.

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi - Again, I know it's paranoid. I've said that twice. The key thing here is that `bottomRef.current` **is what changes** (though probably only once, from `undefined` to an element), and so it's the dependency.